# Handlebars not rendering even though I am passing in my variables

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I'm creating a todo list but my handlebars isn't rendering. I'm using passport for google auth and I believe I'm storing my variables in my comments below. I'm also using mongodb and when I add todos, they are being stored in the database.

According to hbs docs, if blocks will not render if argument returns `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `""`, `0`, or `[]`. I'm passing in the variables but no errors are logged.

https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time. Please see my comments in the code below.

Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const todosController = require("../controllers/todos");

router.get("/", todosController.getTodos);

router.post("/addTodo", todosController.addTodo);

module.exports = router;
```

Controller:

```
const Todo = require("../models/todos");

module.exports = {
  getTodos: async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.user);
    // console.log(req.user.googleId);
    try {
      const todoItems = await Todo.find({ googleId: req.user.googleId }); // get all todos that match googleId
      const itemsLeft = await Todo.countDocuments({
        googleId: req.user.googleId,
        done: false,
      }); // getting variables from google auth here
      console.log(itemsLeft);
      
      res.render("todos.hbs", {
        todo: todoItems, // Storing variables here and passing them on into hbs.
        left: itemsLeft,
        user: req.user,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },
  
  addTodo: async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body.todoItem);
    try {
      await Todo.create({
        todo: req.body.todoItem,
        done: false,
        googleId: req.user.googleId,
      });
      console.log("To do has been added!");
      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  },
};
```

Handlebars template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="flexContainer">
        <h1 class="title main-font center">Welcome {{user.displayName}}</h1> 
        {{!-- not rendering. Maybe I need to use lean()? --}}
      </header>

      <form class="center" action="/todos/addTodo" method="POST">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="todoItem" />
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
      </form>

      <div class="to-do-list flexContainer">
        <ul class="task-list center">
          {{#each todo}}
            {{#if todo.done}} // 
            <span class="complete">{{todo.todo}}</span>
            {{else}}
            <h1>unknown</h1>
            <span class="incomplete">{{todo.todo}}</span>
            {{/if}}
            <span class="fa fa-trash delete-todo"></span>
          {{/each}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <h4 class="main-font center">Left to do: {{left}}</h4>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express"); // handle CRUD api // <-- here
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars"); // <-- here
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); // talk to database
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const passport = require("passport"); // handle all auth
const session = require("express-session"); // keep users logged in
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo"); // pass session to database. Can get back in even if server restarts.
const connectDB = require("./config/db"); // how we connect to database

// Load config
// config.env is where all the global variables are stored.
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

// Passport config
require("./config/passport")(passport);

// This call connects to mongodb.
connectDB();

// Initialize app
const app = express();

// Body parser
// this allows us to look into data that was sent from forms
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}

// Handlebars <-- here
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs"); // <-- here

// Sessions
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/todos", require("./routes/todos"));

app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on PORT ${PORT}`)
);
```

EDIT: added my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

Comment: There may be a few issues here. I would be curious to know if some parts of your template are rendering. One issue I can identify is within the `{{#each todo}}`. You don't have a local `todo` reference - as in `{{#if todo.done}}` - it should just be `{{#if done}}`. This is because the context when within the loop is the current iteration of the loop. Alternatively, you could use `as` to create a `todo` reference, as in `{{#each todo as |todo|}}` - that would make the rest of the template correct. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/dbsfpw21/

Comment: Nothing is rendering, including `user.displayName` and `left`, which counts the number of incomplete todos. The local `todo` is coming from the `res.render` function with the `todo: todoItems` line, or at least that's what *should* be happening.

I'll keep working on it. Maybe something is not linking properly. I was looking at hbs answers from 2015 and they link the controller with the hbs template using a script tag. I didn't see this as a requirement in the hbs docs so maybe they updated it.

Comment: The script tag is for Handlebars used on the client-side. As you are using Express, you are executing Handlebars on the server. It may help if you share your Handlebars configuration and your project's views' file structure.

Comment: I've added my file structure in the edits. I'm new to this and I'm not sure what Handlebars configuration means. EDIT: I think the toughest part for me is there is no error on the console so I can't identify where in my code am I making the mistake.

Comment: There should be some code that tells Express to use Handlebars as a view engine - somewhere you are calling `app.engine`. I assume you are using something like Express Handlebars: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars

Comment: I've added my app.js and yes, there is `require()`, `app.engine()`, and `app.use()` for express-handlebars.

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me immediately. Have you tried logging your values, like `todoItems` to make sure they are what you think they are?

Comment: So I solved this problem. Turns out I had two get routes to `"/"`. Now I have other problems to solve but at least I'm making progress. Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: It might be a good idea to close this question as the solution wasn't really relevant to what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

you may be missing the Front-end link to the Handlebars JavaScript

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
```

if you want you can download the JavaScript file and reference it locally in your project. I hope it helps.